# How to get the dependencies that are loaded during build

Tags: gradle

Somewhere, gradle must know what dependencies that it loaded into itself and which that were put into the build folder.

How do I programatically obtain a datastructure of the dependencies (jars, zips etc) that was downloaded and included into my build?

Comment: println configurations.runtime.files

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

> that were put into the build folder

For example, in case you are building ordinary Jar file (not an uber jar), Gradle resolves project's dependencies, then it downloads them into its cache and during compile process, it creates classpath by concatenating all URIs to those dependencies stored in cache and passes this list to `javac`. Then most probably it also creates a POM file having definition of all of these dependencies. If you build War archive, then probably Gradle copies the dependencies from cache to `/lib`.

To obtain the resolved list of dependencies for `compile` configuration call

`configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration`

to list all files that were resolved, invoke

```
configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.each { file ->
  println file
}
```

The call to `resolvedConfiguration` actually resolves the configuration in case it has not been resolved yet.